# State of React child doesn't update after updating parent component

Tags: reactjs, components

I try to update the `center` prop of the child `BaseMap` component via the parent component. Even though the parent components state gets updated (and I could read the new updated properties in the `console.log`), it is not passed down to the child properties.

The last thing I tried was the `componentWillReceiveProps` method. It still doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
const google = window.google;
let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      avatar: '',
      username: 'someUse03',
      realName: '',
      location: '',
      followers: '',
      following: '',
      repos: '',
      address: '',
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBox fetchUser={this.fetchUser.bind(this)}/>
        <Card data={this.state} />
        <BaseMap />
      </div>
    );
  }

  fetchApi(url) {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          avatar: data.avatar_url,
          username: data.login,
          realName: data.name,
          location: data.location,
          followers: data.followers,
          following: data.following,
          repos: data.public_repos,
          address: geocoder.geocode({'address': data.location}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
              var coords = [];
              var results = results.map((i) => {
                i.geometry.location = i.geometry.location
                          .toString()
                          .replace(/[()]/g, '')
                          .split(', ');
                coords.push(i.geometry.location[0], i.geometry.location[1]);
                results = coords.map((i) => {
                  return parseInt(i, 10)
                });
                return results;
              });
            } else {
              alert('Geocoding was not successfull because ' + status)
            }
          })
        })
      });
  }

  fetchUser(username) {
    let url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`;

    this.fetchApi(url);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let url = `https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.username}`;

    this.fetchApi(url);
  }

}

export default App;
```

This is the child component:

```
BaseMap extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                center: [41, 21],
            }
        }

        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            this.setState({ center: nextProps.address});
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <Col md={10} mdPull={1}>
                    <div className="map">
                        <GoogleMap
                        bootstrapURLKeys={'AIzaSyBhzwgQ3EfoIRYT70fbjrWASQVwO63MKu4'}
                        center={this.state.center}
                        zoom={11}>
                        </GoogleMap>
                    </div>
                </Col>
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fetching inside the render method. this is a big **NO NO**.
Instead do that in the `componentDidMount` [life cycle method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Another thing that may or may not be related to your problem, Arrays are reference types, that means if you mutate them they still points to the same ref in the memory. this could be problematic for the [Reconciliation and diff algorithm of react](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) to determine if the state indeed  changed.
when you want to change or return a new array you could simply use the [ES6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
const nextArray = [...nextProps.address]
this.setState({ center: nextArray });
```

**EDIT**
Ok i forgot to mention the most important part here :)
You are not passing any props to `<BaseMap />` so you won't get any helpful data in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: Are you pointing to the  `<SearchBox fetchUser={this.fetchUser.bind(this)}/>` line?

Comment: Yes. The general pattern for things that should be fetched when the page loads is to trigger an action from componentWillMount, for example fetchUser. This in turn will then set the state when the data has been retreived. If it's async have a look at sagas or thunks. Thunks are easier to learn but sagas are arguably used more, right now at least.

Comment: @WillyG you mean `componentDidMount`. You should never fetch on `componentWillMount` or in the `constructor`. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Comment: @BirdMars look at my edit to the answer, i forgot to mention an important part

Comment: @Sag1v Thanks! But passing a `center={this.state.address}` line in the `<BaseMap />` still doesn't pass it to the child... Uuuugh.

Comment: @BirdMars that because you don't realy fetch the data in the parent, and the state doesnt realy hold the `address` object. call the fetch in `componentDidMount` of the parent and update the state there. this will trigger a second render that will pass in the new state with the `address` object (the first render will be with an empty state.address of course until you finish the fetch and update the state)